# HMAC-SHA1 in C++ using OpenSSL

Tags: c++, openssl, hmacsha1

In the code I need to maintain there's a bit which screws Oauth signature. I've narrowed down the problem to HMAC-SHA1 digest calculation. There's this code that does that:

```
  char key[256]="", base[1024]="";
  char hmacsha1[1024]="", hmac_base64[1024]="";
  unsigned int hmacsha1_len;

  HMAC(EVP_sha1(), key, strlen(key), (unsigned char *)data, strlen(data), (unsigned char *)hmacsha1, &hmacsha1_len);

  gBase64CRInclude = FALSE;
  BPos = 0;
  XPos = 0;
  SPos = 0;
  for (i=0;i<hmacsha1_len;i++) {
    ch = hmacsha1[i];
    BBuf[BPos++] = ch;
    if (BPos == 3) {
      encodebase64Mem(hmac_base64, &SPos);
      BBuf[0]=BBuf[1]=BBuf[2]=BBuf[3] = 0;
    }
  }
  encodebase64Mem(hmac_base64, &SPos);
  hmac_base64[SPos] = 0;
  printf("HMAC-SHA1: %s\n", hmac_base64);
```

Now `encodebase64Mem()` seems to be okay, since other strings are encoded right. I've seen similar examples around but still cannot figure out why digest is calculated incorrectly. Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example? Given a certain input, you're getting what as output, and you expect what? Aside from `key` being an empty string, the `HMAC()` call looks fine. Also, why 1024 bytes for `hmacsha1`? You know it'll be 160 bytes.

Comment: key and data are just usual strings you can expect for OAuth as encription key and message body correspondingly. I have a suspicion that base64 encoding of the signature is not done right.

Comment: Maybe try http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html and print to hex the result of the HMAC call in your code, see if they're coming out the same, then you can blame the base64.

Comment: Thanks! It turned out I just forgot to append "&" at the end of the key, which rendered signature incorrect.